# MVC post model- Collection property has no elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
 {%>
<%: Html.AntiForgeryToken()%>
<%: Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Id) %>
<% for (int i = 0; i < Model.CollectionOfItems.Count; i++)
   {%>
  <%: Html.HiddenFor(m =>Model.CollectionOfItems.ToList()[i].Id)%>
  <%: Html.HiddenFor(m =>Model.CollectionOfItems.ToList()[i].Name)%>
  <%: Html.EditorFor( m => Model.CollectionOfItems.ToList()[i].NumbersToState)%>
 <%} %>
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
<%} %>
```

The problem is when I post the Model to the Controller action. The count of "CollectionOfItems" is 0. Model state is valid and there is no compile error.

Edit 1: I received the property model - Id.
Edit 2: Controller action

```
 [HttpPost]
       [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Action(Model ReceivedModel)
        {
            try
            {
               //here i have break point to check value of ReceivedModel
              // here i can read the value id of the received model - for ex.: 5
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return ""
            }
        }
```

Edit 3:
Model is Entity genereted from ADO Entity Data Model

```
public partial class Model
    {
        public Model()
        {
            this.CollectionOfItems= new HashSet<Items>();
        }
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Items> CollectionOfItems{ get; set; }
    }
```

Edit 4:

This is the result from the foreach loop

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." name="[0].Id" type="hidden" value="21">
```

Comment: Can you show the controller method where you are creating the model?

Comment: Post the controller code please!

Comment: Can you get rid of ".ToList()"? Also, can you post the Html source that your view renders?

Comment: If i remove .ToList() it gives me compile error because "CollectionOfItems" is collection. Model is Entity genereted from ADO Entity Data Model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .ToList() is breaking the binding to the parent object.

This is one place (of many) where the ViewModel concept shows its worth. If you introduce one, and hydrate it with that Model object (as opposed to just using the data model as a view model), you should be able to get past this.

Example ViewModel for this scenario:

```
public class ViewModel1 // Find a better name ;)
{
    public ViewModel1 ()
    {
    }
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public List<Items> Items{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is very good but i can`t use my models, only entity genereted from ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Comment: I change my program by adding ViewModel as you proposed and it solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. The problem was the `Name` attribute of each field. Each `Name`has to be unique and correspond correctly to the Model. Below is what you need to have in order to POST the ICollection.

```
   <% for (int i = 0; i < Model.CollectionOfItems.Count; i++)
    {%>
       <%: Html.Hidden("CollectionOfItems[" + i + "].Id", Model.CollectionOfItems.ElementAt(i).Id)%>
       <%: Html.Hidden("CollectionOfItems[" + i + "].Name", Model.CollectionOfItems.ElementAt(i).Name)%>
       <%: Html.Editor("CollectionOfItems[" + i + "].NumbersToState", Model.CollectionOfItems.ElementAt(i).NumbersToState)%>
   <%} 
   %>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a model binding problem while using the collection you have make sure the the names of the collection are properly set for the model binding to work.

here is the interesting which will help you to fix your issue http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/